# https://branch.io/ value is changed in ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsuserdefaults, branch.io

We have implemented the branch.io in our project. we have used a newlink with the name of "XXX" and passed the "XXX" into our server in the entire app and terminated the app and generate the new link in with the name of "YYY". when we click the second link "YYY". In the service we get a previous name "XXX" and New name "YYY"? So the user can't able to use the correct name. What's the reason for this? **when we click the new link. New link only get update into server not the old one.**

```
 let branch: Branch = Branch.getInstance()
        branch.initSession(launchOptions: launchOptions, automaticallyDisplayDeepLinkController: true, deepLinkHandler: { params, error in
            if error == nil {
                if let newValue = params?["Name"] as? String {}
```

**Once we get the value from the newValue.we stored the value into UserDefaul**ts.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, please submit a ticket to support@branch.io where we can better help you! More information will be needed to investigate and assist you with this issue that should not be shared in a public forum! We look forward to assisting you soon!

Cheers,
Joie